# How to convert csv to multiMap in java?

Tags: java, csv, multimap

I'm dealing with some data like the following, the first column is the trade id, the second column is the simulation id(duplicate a lot), the third column is some stupid date also quite duplicated, the forth one is the present value of a trade, mostly it is just 0, but any other value should be quite unique.

```
41120634|1554|20150203|-509057.56
40998001|1554|20150203|0
40960705|1554|20150203|0
40998049|1554|20150203|0
41038826|1554|20150203|0
41081136|1554|20150203|-7198152.23
41120653|1554|20150203|-319.436349
41081091|1554|20150203|-4.28520907E+009
```

I've decided to use a data structure as follows:

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,List<Map<Integer,Float>>>
```

Then my csv will be saved like:

```
 {20150203:{1554:[{41120634:-509057.56,41120634:0,...}]}}
```

My question is how to convert such a csv file to my intended data structure efficiently?

Comment: Share what you have tried so far, we can get started from there. There is no  other way than reading it line by line say `List<String[]` and constructing desired data structure. With Java 8 it will be lesser code.

Comment: You haven't explicitly told us what the logical hierarchy should be.  From your example we can partially deduce it's `Date->SimulationID->???`.  Where are `A1:B1`, etc in your input data? There's not enough information in your question for anyone to help you.

Comment: Unless you need your data specifically saved like the structure you listed above, I would recommend making a Java Class to store the fields and then you can read in the lines and parse them into ArrayList<MyObject> or Map<ID, MyObject>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to implement would be a structure like `Map<K1, Map<K2, Map<K3, V>>>`. This format is called `NestedMap`, in this case a `NestedMap3`, three keys and one value.

It is very easy to implement using inheritance since a `NestedMap3` internally uses a `Map<K1, NestedMap2<K2, K3, V>>` and the `NestedMap2` uses a `Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>`.

Next you should think about where to use a `Map` and where to use a multiple container like `Pair<A, B>`, `Triple<A, B, C>`, etc.
If your values change frequently, use a container like Pair. If your values are quite often the same, use a `Map`. Based on this you may mix some values, for example a `Map<K, Triple<A, B, C>>` might be good if the later values change frequently.

In your provided scenario the second and third value are often the same. So I suggest to use a `NestedMap3<Integer, Integer, Integer, Float>` in your case.

First the code to setup the data structure, I'll assume your input are lines given as `String` stored in `inputLines`:

```
NestedMap3<Integer, Integer, Integer, Float> map = new NestedMap3<>();
for (String line : inputLines) {
    String[] values = inputLines.split("|");
    map.put(toInt(values[0]), toInt(values[1]), toInt(values[2]), toFloat(values[3]));
}
```

Of course we also need to implement `toInt` and `toFloat`:

```
public Integer toInt(final String value) {
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
}

public Float toFloat(final String value) {
    return Float.parseFloat(value);
}
```

And finally the implementation of `NestedMap3` and `NestedMap2`:

```
public class NestedMap3<K1, K2, K3, V> {

    private final Map<K1, NestedMap2<K2, K3, V>> mK1ToK2ToK3V = 
        new HashMap<K1, NestedMap2<K2, K3, V>>();

    public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, V value) {
                NestedMap2<K2, K3, V> k2tok3toV = mK1ToK2ToK3V.get(key1);
            if (k2tok3toV == null) {
                k2tok3toV = new NestedMap2<>();
                mK1ToK2ToK3V.put(key1, k2tok3toV);
            }
        return k2tok3toV.put(key2, key3, value);
        }

        public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3) {
                final NestedMap2<K2, K3, V> k2tok3toV = mK1ToK2ToK3V.get(key1);
            if (k2tok3toV == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return k2tok3toV.get(key2, key3);
            }
    }

    public Map<K3, V> get(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
        final NestedMap2<K2, K3, V> k2toV = mK1ToK2ToK3V.get(key1);
            if (k2toV == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return k2toV.get(key2);
            }
    }

    public NestedMap2<K2, K3, V> get(K1 key1) {
        return mK1ToK2ToK3V.get(key1);
    }

    public Set<K1> keySet() {
        return mK1ToK2ToK3V.keySet();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mK1ToK2ToK3V.clear();
    }
}

public class NestedMap2<K1, K2, V> {

    private final Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mK1ToK2ToV = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();

    public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
    Map<K2, V> k2toV = mK1ToK2ToV.get(key1);
    if (k2toV == null) {
        k2toV = new HashMap<>();
        mK1ToK2ToV.put(key1, k2toV);
    }
    return k2toV.put(key2, value);
    }

    public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
    final Map<K2, V> k2toV = mK1ToK2ToV.get(key1);
    if (k2toV == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return k2toV.get(key2);
    }
    }

    public Map<K2,V> get(K1 key1) {
    return mK1ToK2ToV.get(key1);
    }

    public Set<K1> keySet() {
    return mK1ToK2ToV.keySet();
    }

    public Iterable<Pair<K1,K2>> keys2() {
    return new Iterable<Pair<K1,K2>>() {

        @Override
        public Iterator<Pair<K1, K2>> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Pair<K1,K2>>() {
                private Iterator<Entry<K1, Map<K2, V>>> mIterator1;
                private Entry<K1, Map<K2, V>> mIterator1Object;
                private Iterator<K2> mIterator2;

                {
                    mIterator1 = mK1ToK2ToV.entrySet().iterator();
                    if (mIterator1.hasNext()) {
                        mIterator1Object = mIterator1.next();
                        mIterator2 = mIterator1Object.getValue().keySet().iterator();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    if (mIterator1Object == null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return mIterator2.hasNext();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Pair<K1, K2> next() {
                    if (mIterator1Object == null) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    } else {
                        if (!mIterator2.hasNext()) {
                            if (!mIterator1.hasNext()) {
                                throw new NoSuchElementException();
                            } else {
                                mIterator1Object = mIterator1.next();
                                assert mIterator1Object.getValue().size() > 0 : "must contain at least one value";
                                mIterator2 = mIterator1Object.getValue().keySet().iterator();
                            }
                        }
                        return new Pair<K1, K2>(mIterator1Object.getKey(), mIterator2.next());
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };

    }

    public Iterable<Triple<K1,K2,V>> entrySet() {
    final ArrayList<Triple<K1,K2,V>> result = new ArrayList<Triple<K1,K2,V>>();
    for (final Entry<K1, Map<K2, V>> entryOuter  : mK1ToK2ToV.entrySet()) {
                for (final Entry<K2, V> entryInner : entryOuter.getValue().entrySet()) {
                    result.add(new Triple<>(entryOuter.getKey(), entryInner.getKey(), entryInner.getValue()));
                }
    }
    return result;
    }

    public void addAll(NestedMap2<K1, K2, V> nestedMap) {
    for (final Triple<K1, K2, V> triple : nestedMap.entrySet()) {
        this.put(triple.getFirst(), triple.getSecond(), triple.getThird());
    }
    }

    public Map<K2, V> remove(K1 k1) {
    return mK1ToK2ToV.remove(k1);
    }

    public V remove(K1 k1, K2 k2) {
        final Map<K2, V> k2ToV = mK1ToK2ToV.get(k1);
    if (k2ToV == null) {
                return null;
    } else {
                return k2ToV.remove(k2);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return mK1ToK2ToV.toString();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mK1ToK2ToV.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Pair and Triple class implementation?

Comment: Of course: http://pastebin.com/kthukFdY. Triple etc. works analogously. Generating equals&hashCode may also be a good idea, depending on the usage.

Comment: thanks, I will add my solution as an reference for others.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an Object that's suitable for your data, after use CSV methods from CommonApache.
[https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Below I found a extract from a code I did and I think it will be useful to you.

```
public class csvToArray {

    public ArrayList<data> csvTo_data() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        // Array to receive parser
        ArrayList<data> your_data = new ArrayList<data>();

        // data Object to receive the CSV data
        data yourData = new data();

        // call open file
        OpenFile of = new OpenFile();

        // get the files in a array of files
        File[] files = of.chosefile();

        // count number of files
        int size = files.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            // CSV Parser can receive FileReader object, so I sent the path name
            CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader(files[i].getAbsolutePath()),
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withSkipHeaderRecord());
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file:" + files[i].getName());

            // iterate to pass from CSV tyoe to Object data type
            for (CSVRecord s : parser) {

                String dataName = s.get(0);
                String dataType = s.get(1);
                int dataSize = Integer.parseInt(s.get(2));

                // get the data from file's path name
                int date = Integer.parseInt(files[i].getName().substring(3, 7));

                yourData = new data(dataName , dataType , dataSize, date);
                your_data.add(yourData);

            }
            parser.close();
        }

        return your_data;
```